# React object property value being duplicated on .push inside loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `handleCreate` function that takes care of taking some user data and inserting it into a database.

Inside the `aliasArr.forEach()` loop I `POST` into my DB new user instances for each element in the `aliasArr` array. This particular code works as expected, if I check the DB, I will find the new members.

After saving the new members, I want to keep the members in the `members` array so I can pass it along to another function.

For this, I'm doing `members.push(memberAttributes);` but if I log the contents of `members` I get the right amount of elements but the `alias` property value is duplicated (all other properties should have the same value cause they are being added into the same role in a batch operation).

If I have two new users, say: `xyz` and `abc`, I get:

```
[
    {alias: "abc", Role: "admin", "grantedBy": "someone"},
    {alias: "abc", Role: "admin", "grantedBy": "someone"},
]
```

Instead of:

```
[
    {alias: "xyz", Role: "admin", "grantedBy": "someone"},
    {alias: "abc", Role: "admin", "grantedBy": "someone"},
]
```

---

Here's the code:

```
 handleCreate = () => {
    const { memberAttributes } = this.state;
    const { role, createRoleMember } = this.props;
    const roleArr = [];
    roleArr.push(role);
    const aliasArr = memberAttributes.alias.split(",");
    let members = [];

    //false hardcoded during debugging.
    if (false /* await aliasIsAdmin(memberAttributes.alias, roleArr) */) { 
      this.setState({ userExists: true }); 
    } else {
      memberAttributes["Granted By"] = window.alias;
      memberAttributes.Role = role;
      memberAttributes.timestamp = Date.now().toString();
      this.handleClose();

      aliasArr.forEach((currAlias) => {
        memberAttributes.alias = currAlias;
        console.log("memberAttributes:", memberAttributes);

        members.push(memberAttributes);
        console.log("members", members);

        const marshalledObj = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall(memberAttributes);

        const params = {
          TableName: "xxx",
          Item: marshalledObj,
        };

        axios.post(
          "https://xxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx",
          params
        );
      });
    }
    createRoleMember(members); //passing members to this function to do more stuff.
  };
```

I'm wondering if this issue is due to `memberAttributes` being part of the component's `state`.

Comment: Try doing `members.push({...memberAttributes});`. This will make a copy of `memberAttributes`

Comment: You're mutating the state.  you have `this.state.memberAttributes` and you're *modifying* `memberAttributes`.  State is immutable.  You must setState to modify it.

Comment: Is writing `members.push({ ...memberAttributes, alias: currAlias });` OK or coukd that break something in react's state? Thank you everyone for your comments and helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are pushing references to the same object into the array after changing a value within that object. So whenever you make the change to `memberAttributes.alias`, it's changing the alias to the most recent one. After that, all references to the same object (which in this case is every item in the `members` array) present the new value in alias.

```js
const obj = { alias: 'abc', role: 'role1' }
const arr = []

arr.push(obj)

obj.alias = 'new alias'

arr.push(obj)

for (var mem of arr) {
  console.log(mem)
}
```

To fix it, you need to create a new object each time and push it onto the array instead, like so:

```js
aliasArr.forEach((currAlias) => {
   // Creates a new object in memory with the same values, but overwrites alias
   const newMemberAttributes = Object.assign(memberAttributes, { alias: currAlias });
   console.log("memberAttributes:", newMemberAttributes);

   members.push(newMemberAttributes);
   console.log("members", members);
   ...
}
```

Similarly, you can use the spread operator to create a deep copy of the object and then reassign alias.

```js
aliasArr.forEach((currAlias) => {
   // Creates a new object in memory with the same values, but overwrites alias
   const newMemberAttributes = { ...memberAttributes };
   newMemberAttributes.alias = currAlias
   console.log("memberAttributes:", newMemberAttributes);

   members.push(newMemberAttributes);
   console.log("members", members);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried  `members.push({ ...memberAttributes, alias: currAlias });` and it worked great, would this be okay to do? Thank you for the explanation and the solution I was going crazy!

Comment: Yep, that works as well, since you're still creating a new object. I separated it across multiple lines for ease of understanding, but shorthanding it like that is totally acceptable. All personal preference.