# Object Push into Array within For Loop/For Each Loop is causing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I would like to give each object in my Array a property that corresponds to an ID.  I've tried this every possible way it seems like, below is the latest.

When I console.log the output individually it all looks good. However, when I run the output.push() and then log output, there are duplicates.

I found the below post which seems very similiar but after applying the changes suggested, I am still facing the same issue--In that I am seeing repeating IDs in the final output.  The IndexID property is not unique and it should be for each iteration.

[React object property value being duplicated on .push inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63676346/react-object-property-value-being-duplicated-on-push-inside-loop)

Simple example first, then actual code example:

```
   flattenedWorkouts.forEach((currAlias,index) =>{
       
        const obj ={}
        const newMemberAttributes = Object.assign(obj, { alias: currAlias });
        newMemberAttributes.alias.indexID= index
                     
            console.log("memberAttributes:", newMemberAttributes);
         
            output.push(newMemberAttributes.alias)
    
    })
```

Snippet of the FlattenedWorkout elements that are incorrect...there are 100 so not including all + i've trimmed down the object:

```
  Array [
      Object {
        "Round": "AMRAP 1",
        "indexID": 6,
   
      },
  Object {
        "Round": "AMRAP 1",
        "indexID": 6,
   
      },
  Object {
        "Round": "AMRAP 1",
        "indexID": 6,
   
      },
```

What I would expect to see:

```
 Object {
        "Round": "AMRAP 1",
        "indexID": 6,
   
      },
  Object {
        "Round": "AMRAP 1",
        "indexID": 7,
   
      },
  Object {
        "Round": "AMRAP 1",
        "indexID": 8,
   
      },
```

Actual Issue. Below is the starting Object.

```js
var WorkoutDetail = [
  //Dummy item to act as begin of carasoul
  {
    RoundID: 1,
    Round: 'AMRAP 1',
    NumberOfSets: 3,
    Activity: [{
        key: '1',
        title: 'AMRAP 1',
        description: "Banded curtsy lunge to side leg raise",
      },
      {
        key: '2',
        title: 'AMRAP 1',
        description: "Inchworm with push-up",
      },
      {
        key: '3',
        title: 'AMRAP 1',
        description: "Static lunge with single arm press",
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    RoundID: 2,
    Round: 'AMRAP 2',
    NumberOfSets: 2,
    Activity: [{
        key: '4',
        title: 'AMRAP 2',
        description: "Side plank to leg extension",
      },
      {
        key: '5',
        title: 'AMRAP 2',
        description: "Burpee to bench jump",
      },
      {
        key: '6',
        title: 'AMRAP 2',
        description: "Banded heel tap jump squat",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    RoundID: 3,
    Round: 'AMRAP 3',
    NumberOfSets: 1,
    Activity: [{
        key: '7',
        title: 'AMRAP 3',
        description: "Weighted pike plank",
      },
      {
        key: '8',
        title: 'AMRAP 3',
        description: "Incline push up",
      },
      { //Dummy item to make as caboose
        key: '9',
        title: 'AMRAP 3',
        description: "Weighted pike plank",
      },
      //Dummy item to make as caboose in carasoul
    ]
  }
]

// Next a Method I am using to loop over this object and * flatten * it out:

var FlatWorkoutDetail = () => {
  var flattenedWorkouts = []
  var iterationNumber = 0

  //Each Round
  WorkoutDetail.forEach(x => {

    for (let i = 1; i <= x.NumberOfSets; i++) {
    
      for (let a = 0; a < x.Activity.length; a++) {
        var obj = x.Activity[a]
        obj.Round = x.Round
        obj.SetNumber = i
        flattenedWorkouts.push(obj)
        iterationNumber++;
      }
    }
  })

  return flattenedWorkouts
}

// Simple forEach Solution:
var FlatWorkoutDetailOutput = (val) => {
  val.forEach((obj, i) => obj.indexID = i);
}

// Execute the functions:
const TestArray = FlatWorkoutDetail()
const TestArray2 = FlatWorkoutDetailOutput(TestArray)

console.log(TestArray);
```

Final output is incorrect. 6 is the starting index and 14 is repeated twice:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Banded curtsy lunge to side leg raise",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 6,
    "key": "1",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Test.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Inchworm with push-up",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 7,
    "key": "2",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout3.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Static lunge with single arm press",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 8,
    "key": "3",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Banded curtsy lunge to side leg raise",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 6,
    "key": "1",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Test.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Inchworm with push-up",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 7,
    "key": "2",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout3.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Static lunge with single arm press",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 8,
    "key": "3",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Banded curtsy lunge to side leg raise",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 6,
    "key": "1",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Test.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Inchworm with push-up",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 7,
    "key": "2",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout3.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 1",
    "SetNumber": 3,
    "description": "Static lunge with single arm press",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 8,
    "key": "3",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 1",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 2",
    "SetNumber": 2,
    "description": "Side plank to leg extension",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 12,
    "key": "4",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 2",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 2",
    "SetNumber": 2,
    "description": "Burpee to bench jump",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 13,
    "key": "5",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 2",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 2",
    "SetNumber": 2,
    "description": "Banded heel tap jump squat",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 14,
    "key": "6",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 2",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 2",
    "SetNumber": 2,
    "description": "Side plank to leg extension",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 12,
    "key": "4",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 2",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 2",
    "SetNumber": 2,
    "description": "Burpee to bench jump",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 13,
    "key": "5",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 2",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 2",
    "SetNumber": 2,
    "description": "Banded heel tap jump squat",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 14,
    "key": "6",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 2",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 3",
    "SetNumber": 1,
    "description": "Weighted pike plank",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 15,
    "key": "7",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 3",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 3",
    "SetNumber": 1,
    "description": "Incline push up",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 16,
    "key": "8",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 3",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
  Object {
    "Round": "AMRAP 3",
    "SetNumber": 1,
    "description": "Weighted pike plank",
    "image": null,
    "indexID": 17,
    "key": "9",
    "time": " 45 Seconds",
    "title": "AMRAP 3",
    "video": "https://boolin-api2.herokuapp.com/fetchImage//Uploads/Game3899-Workout4.mp4",
  },
]
```

Comment: Please post sufficient code to replicate the issue, along with sample data, expected output and actual output. See [*How to create a minimal, reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added some more detail

Comment: try removing everything you've got inside the forEach and just do `output.push({ ...currAlias, indexID: index });`

Comment: also, you could use map instead `const output = flattenedWorkouts.map((currAlias,index) => ({ ...currAlias, indexID: index }));`

Comment: the structure of the flattenedWorkouts is like this [{},{},{}], right?
and you wanted to have these elements [{"Round": "AMRAP 1","indexID:6}, {"Round": "AMRAP 1","indexID:7}, {"Round": "AMRAP 1","indexID:8}]

Comment: Correct on the desired format. I’ll try the other solutions in a bit when I am home

Comment: There's no need to create new arrays or objects. If the intention is just to add an *indexID* property then `flattenedWorkouts.forEach((obj, i) => obj.indexID = i)` does exactly that.

Comment: I've tidied the code somewhat, reduced the data and turned it into a runnable snippet. The issue is around the two *for* loops, you're creating duplicate references to the same object but I can't work out what you're trying to do. Please post a sample of the expected output. Creating function expressions that take no arguments and simply use global variables is pointless, better to just run the code as global code. Also, put in semicolons to end statements, leaving them out does nothing useful and potentially creates difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Also, *forEach* always returns *undefined*, so that's the value assigned to *TestArray2*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what else is going on in your code, but you're mutating the initial object a lot. Mutation is the source of all evil, try to avoid it like COVID.

Do this, it should solve your index problem.

```js
var FlatWorkoutDetailOutput = (val) =>{
                              // shallow copy of the object, it only works cause the object is flat
  return val.map((obj, i) => ({...obj, indexID: i}));

}
```

Now `TestArray` will have the same bug as before, but `TestArray2` will have the correct `indexID`.

As a rule of thumb, every time you want an object to look differently than it originally was, create a new object based on the original one.
If you have an array of objects, use `map` and return a new array with new objects based on the original objects.

So in your previous code instead of doing this

```js
var obj = x.Activity[a]
obj.Round =  x.Round
obj.SetNumber = i
flattenedWorkouts.push(obj)
iterationNumber ++;
```

do this

```js
var originalObj = x.Activity[a]
var newObj = { ...originalObj } // this is a shallow copy, if you want to copy deep nested objects look up some library
newObj.SetNumber = i
flattenedWorkouts.push(newObj)
iterationNumber ++;
```

Comment: that was it!! Thank you both for the insight. Feel like I owe you cookies haha

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate index values in the result can't be explained by the posted code.

In the code:

```
flattenedWorkouts.forEach((currAlias,index) =>{
```

There's no sample for *flattenedWorkouts*, so I'll use:

```
[{name: 'A'},{name: 'B'},{name: 'C'}];
```

Then there is:

```
    const obj ={}
    const newMemberAttributes = Object.assign(obj, { alias: currAlias });
```

The result is that *obj* and *newMemberAttributes* reference the same object. It's the same as:

```
let obj = {alias: currAlias};
let newMemberAttributes = obj;
```

*Object.assign* does a shallow copy, so:

```
newMemberAttributes.alias === currAlias
```

i.e. the original object passed to *forEach* is assigned to *newMemberAttributes.alias*, its properties and values aren't copied. Any changes to the original object will be reflected in *newMemberAttributes.alias*.

Later there is:

```
        output.push({ ...obj, alias: currAlias })
```

*output* isn't defined anywhere so I've added `let output = []`. As *obj* references the same object as *newMemberAttributes*, it doesn't matter which one is used.

The destructuring of *obj* and merging with *alias* means that duplicate properties are overridden. *obj* only has two properties: *alias* and *indexID*, so its own *alias* property is overridden in the merge with *currAlias*. This has little practical effect as the values are identical anyway (i.e. they're both references to the *currAlias* object).

If all you want to do is add an *indexID* property to the objects in *flattenedWorkouts*, then just do:

```
flattenedWorkouts.forEach((obj, i) => obj.indexID = i);
```

If, on the other hand, you want to copy the objects first, then use *map* with *Object.assign* to copy them before adding *indexID*:

```
let output = flattenedWorkouts.map((obj, i) => Object.assign({}, obj, {indexID: i}));
```

Note that *Object.assign* does a shallow copy, so deeper objects are references, not copies.

The following code that might clear things up. Or not.

```js
let flattenedWorkouts = [{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'C'}];
let output = [];

flattenedWorkouts.forEach((currAlias, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  let newMemberAttributes = Object.assign(obj, {alias: currAlias});
  
  console.log('obj === newMemberAttributes: ' + (obj === newMemberAttributes));
  console.log('obj.alias === currAlias    : ' + (obj.alias === currAlias));
  
  newMemberAttributes.alias.indexID = index;
  
  console.log('iteration ' + index + ' memberAttributes\n', newMemberAttributes);

  output.push({ ...obj, alias: currAlias});
})

console.log('output ' + JSON.stringify(output));
```

If the intention is copy across the properties and values and add an *indexID* property, consider the following based on *forEach* (but also see *map* example below):

```js
let arr = [{name: 'A'},{name: 'B'},{name: 'C'}];
let result = [];

arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
  let newObj = Object.assign({},obj, {indexID: i} );
  result.push(newObj);  
});

console.log(result);

// Check that original array objects aren't changed
console.log(
  'Compare values:\n' + 
  JSON.stringify(arr[0]) + '\n' +
  JSON.stringify(result[0])
);
// Check identity
console.log('arr[0] ===  result[0] ? ' + (arr[0] ===  result[0]));
```

Example using [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let arr = [{name: 'A'},{name: 'B'},{name: 'C'}];

let output = arr.map((obj, i) => ({...obj, indexID: i}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Awesome in depth analysis RobG.  I agree with everything you said, you explained it very well. However when I tried to implement it, still came across the same issue. This has been more interactive than I was anticpating so I went ahead and put up the full code example.  I suspect maybe it is a different issue entirely? Possibly related to how I am creating the starting Array